# How do I call my "show" method without any parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I have this in my routes.rb file

```
resources :votes
```

When I run rake routes, it gives

```
   votes GET    /votes(.:format)                   votes#index
         POST   /votes(.:format)                   votes#create
new_vote GET    /votes/new(.:format)               votes#new
```

edit_vote GET    /votes/:id/edit(.:format)          votes#edit
        vote GET    /votes/:id(.:format)               votes#show

My question is how can I call my "/show" method without any parameters?  If someone doesn't supply an ID, I want to generate a random result using this controller method

```
  def show
    id = params[:id]
    # If there is no person selected based on the param, choose one randomly
    if !id.present?
      if current_user
        @person = Person.joins("LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = people.user_id")
                        .where("people.user_id IS NULL")
                        .order("RANDOM()").limit(1).first
      end
      if @person.nil?
        @person = Person.order("RANDOM()").limit(1).first
      end
    else
      @person = Person.find_by_id(id)
      if current_user
        @vote = Vote.where(person_id: id, user_id: current_user.id).first || Vote.new
      end
    end
  end
```

But right now when I type "/votes" into my browser, it dies with the error

```
The action 'index' could not be found for VotesController
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least when you use `resources` — `resources` generates a standard group of routes that adhere to RESTful practices. In your case, it's generating `get '/votes/:id', to: 'votes#show'`

Because there is no matching param, it assumes that you're trying to go to `votes#index`

If you want to match both, I would do something like this in your `routes.rb`: `get '/votes(/:id)', to: 'votes#show'` the parens denote an optional param. You may need to put this prior to your `resources` block, or change your `resources` block to omit the `show` action.

More on params: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.1/routing.html#bound-parameters